A question that involves continuity and differentiability
Suppose $f:(a, b) \to \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function  at $x=c$ where $a<c<b$ and $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x) $ exists then this limit is equal to $f'(c) $.
I actually tried in this way!
$$\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to c}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
 $$ which is same as $\lim_{h\to 0}\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
 $(I do not know the validity of this step) which in turn gives $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}...(1)$ (Because of continuity of $f$). Finally the limit (1) will be $f'(c)$
I do not know if I could use  $$\lim_{x\to a}\lim_{h\to b}g(x, h) =\lim_{h\to b} \lim_{x\to a}g(x, h)...(2)$$ I am also curious to know, such limit interchangeability possible?  Is there such result in limit evaluating methods?. And is there another way to prove first statement.?

If I am not misreading it, this looks very ill posed. First, $f$ is a function of one variable not of two. What does those limits even mean?

Do you assume $f$ to be differentiable on at least $(a,b)\setminus {c}$? If so, I suggest to use the Mean Value Theorem.

Your hypothesis says only that $f$ is continuous at $c$, you can't consider $\lim_{x\to c} f'(x)$ which implies that $f$ is differentiable around $c$.

Downvoting and voting to close, as OP lacks effort to prove the proposition.

Thanks a ton to Mathematician 42.

I'll assume that $f$ is differentiable except possibly at $c$. For each $x\in (a,b)$ different from $c$, the Mean Value Theorem ensures the existence of a $c_x$ strictly between $x$ and $c$ such that
$$\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f'(c_x).$$
Taking the limit $\lim_{x\to c}$ of the above expression, we find that $f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c}f'(c_x)=\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$ where the right-hand side exists by assumption.

How do we know the lhs is $f'(c) $ in the second last step of yours?

@YBR : It's obtained by taking the limit of $x\to c$ of the left-hand side of the equation $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f'(c_x)$. Indeed, $\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}= f'(c)$ by definition of the derivative in a point. At the sime time, the right-hand side (after taking the same limit of $x\to c$) becomes $\lim_{x\to c}f'(c_x)$. Since for each $x$, $c_x$ lies strictly between $x$ and $c$, we see that it really boils down to the limit $\lim_{z\to c}f'(z)$ (which exists by assumption).

To make the last part of my previous comment really rigorous (so that you can replace $\lim_{x\to c}f'(c_x)$ by $\lim_{z\to c}f'(z)$, you can use Theorem one of https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408s/CurrentWeb/LM11-1-7.php#:~:text=Evaluating%20limits%20of%20sequences%20using%20limits%20of%20functions&text=Theorem%201%3A%20Let%20f%20be,get%20the%20limits%20of%20sequences. (you can evaluate these limits by replacing them by ordinary limits of sequences, independent of the sequence chosen to approach $c$).
